# Setting enumitem options for an entire document

Tags: enumitem

What commands do I put in my preamble to set enumeration labels once and for all for a document.  I'm not finding it easy to get this information from Bezos's instructions in `enumitem.pdf`.

I want my lists to follow canonical outline ordering: capital Roman for top level; capital alphabet for next level; arabic for next level; lowercase alphabet for next level.

Comment: You asked two similar questions, I answered the specific needs for `Roman, A,arabic,a` in the other question and showed the possible use of options here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Global `enumerate` options (for example) can be specified with `\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=....,other options}` (here for the 1st level)

However, instead of misusing the standard way of `enumerate`, a cloned version with `\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{4}` should be used rather.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={(\Alph*)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}

Start again:

\begin{enumerate}
\item Another first item
\item Another second item
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the asterisk in "\Alph*" mean.  I did look this up in enumitem.pdf, but I couldn't quite understand the answer.

Comment: All `enumitem` label possibilities such as `\Alph*`, `\arabic*` use the star to indicate, that the command `\Alph{enum...}`  etc. is to be used, i.e. the counter formatting macro for the current level of enumeration. `enum...` can be `enumi`, `enumii`, `enumiii` or `enumiv`, if a standard `enumeration` list is used. Beware of using `label*={(\Alph*)}` however. In this case, the higher level label is prepended to the current output